# How to toggle lines on and off in R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am plotting a graph using the Plot_ly package in R Shiny. Right now I am creating a graph with many lines on it and I would like to know if it is possible for the user to toggle the lines on and off using the checkbox input.

Here is a sample of my server side code:

```
output$site_filter <- renderUI({
    selectInput("site_filter", "Sites"
                sort(unique(site_list$sites), decreasing = FALSE))
  })

output$plots <- renderPlotly({

forecast_detail <- forecast[forecast$site == input$site_filter,]

actual_detail <- actual[actual$site == input$site_filter,]

p <- plot_ly() %>%
      add_lines(x = forecast_detail$date, y = forecast_detail$total,
                name = 'Forecast', line = list(color = 'purple')) %>%
      add_lines(x = actual_detail$date, y = actual_detail$total,
                name = 'Actual', line = list(color = 'blue'))

})
```

For my ui side, I created the checkbox like this:

```
fluidRow(checkboxInput("Actuals", "Actual Line", value = TRUE))
```

Is there a way I could use this checkbox input to toggle the actual lines on and off? I've been trying to use an if statement before the add_lines command but I get an error that states it is not logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the first group of lines and add the second group based on a condition triggered by your checkbox. It is hard to come up with a working solution without a reproducible example but something like this should do the job:

```
output$plots <- renderPlotly({

  forecast_detail <- forecast[forecast$site == input$site_filter,]
  actual_detail <- actual[actual$site == input$site_filter,]

  p <- plot_ly() %>%
    add_lines(
      x = forecast_detail$date, 
      y = forecast_detail$total,
      name = 'Forecast', 
      line = list(color = 'purple')
    )

  if(!is.null(input$Actuals)) {
    p <- p %>%
      add_lines(
        x = actual_detail$date, 
        y = actual_detail$total,
        name = 'Actual', 
        line = list(color = 'blue')
      )
  }

  return(p)

})
```

Comment: This works if you change "if(!is.null(input$Actuals))" to "if(!isFALSE(input$Actuals))". Thanks!

Comment: Sure, that depends on your implementation.